# Change table's schema name but cannot transfer a schema bound object

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

The schema name **menu** and the table **dbo.Dinner** has already existed in the database.

I would like to change

FROM

```
dbo.Dinner
```

TO

```
menu.Dinner
```

Using this query:

```
ALTER SCHEMA menu TRANSFER dbo.Dinner
```

And I get error message:

```
cannot transfer a schema bound object
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: microsoft sql server

Comment: I *assume* that you have another object referring to `dbo.Dinner` with the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` clause in the `ALTER`/`CREATE`? Is so, you'll need to `DROP` those objects, move the schema, and then recreate them (with the object name updated)

Comment: Is Dinner table has referenced by foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I suspect that you have at least one object that uses the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` clause in its `CREATE`/`ALTER` and therefore you can't change the table object. You'll need to `DROP` and recreate those object. As an example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Dinner (ID int, Meal varchar(20));
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.Dinners WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    SELECT DISTINCT Meal
    FROM dbo.Dinner;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA menu;
GO
ALTER SCHEMA menu TRANSFER dbo.Dinner; --Fails
GO
DROP VIEW dbo.Dinners;
GO
ALTER SCHEMA menu TRANSFER dbo.Dinner; --Succeeds
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.Dinners WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    SELECT DISTINCT Meal
    FROM menu.Dinner;
GO
--Ceal up
DROP VIEW dbo.Dinners;
DROP TABLE menu.Dinner;
DROP SCHEMA menu;
```

You can get a list of the dependances by using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.[name],
       o.[type_desc]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
     JOIN sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE sed.referenced_schema_name = N'dbo'
  AND sed.referenced_entity_name = N'Dinner';
```

Comment: Do you use the view as the schema bound object as an example? I am not sure what the schema bound object related to table Dinner is. But I can find this in the list of the dependencies using the query you provided?

Comment: Yes, to both, @Erick

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!! Currently I can't test it. I will test it immediately after holidays.

Answer (score 0):

We are also getting this error, exactly because we are using materialized views with schema binding.

We ended up re-creating the objects in the new schema and using `insert` `select` statements to copy over the data to the new schema.

The steps for each table are:

- drop table in target schema
- create table in target schema
- insert from source to target schema

Here is a sample script:

```
drop table if exists [target_schema].[dim_forexchange]
go

CREATE TABLE [target_schema].[dim_forexchange](
    [time_year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [local_acct_curr] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DivisorFXtoGBP] [float] NOT NULL,
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [target_schema].[dim_forexchange] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [id]
GO

insert into [target_schema].[dim_forexchange] select * from [dbo].[dim_forexchange];
go
```